# create a new column in mysql as the difference between two columns

Tags: mysql

I wonder if I can create a new column in mysql table as the difference between two columns

I tried this

```
cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE options_20161229 ADD daysuntillexpiration INT(6)" )
cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO options_20161229 (daysuntillexpiration) VALUES ('Expiration-Datadate')")
```

However, it was wrong syntax.

Any Idea please.
Many Thanks

Comment: please show the table descripton and some sample data with expected result

Comment: And first try remove the singlecodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [virtual column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

> As of MySQL 5.7.6, CREATE TABLE supports the specification of
>   generated columns. Values of a generated column are computed from an
>   expression included in the column definition.

```
ALTER TABLE Expiration-Datadate ADD daysuntillexpiration INT AS (Expiration-Datadate)
```

Now you don't even need that insert because mysql will calculate the column data dynamically and give you the result

If you are on an older version of mysql you can use CREATE VIEW for the same effect

```
 CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT *, Expiration-Datadate as d from  mytable
```